# Is it possible to return different wsdls for different contracts on the same service?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF service implementing two contracts on two different endpoints. I would like a client to be able to point at an endpoint (rather than the base address of the service) and get the wsdl just for the contract implemented on that endpoint (rather than a wsdl containing all contracts).

Is this possible? If so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting up the service like shown below (with a single SVC file if hosting in IIS)

```
<services>
    <service name="YourOrg.YourService">

        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="YourOrg.IYourServiceThisContract" />
        <endpoint address="That"
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="YourOrg.IYourServiceThatContract" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

Set each contract as a separate service **class** (with its own SVC file in the same IIS website)

```
<services>
    <service name="YourOrg.ThisService">

        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="YourOrg.IYourServiceThisContract" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>

    <service name="YourOrg.ThatService">

        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="YourOrg.IYourServiceThatContract" />
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Would this mean that they both had to be on different ports?

Comment: They would use the same port with the configuration shown in the answer by default in IIS. Using different ports can be done in IIS for the same "website" with host headers. Since WCF isn't really "URL aware", it wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: I should have clarified the question - it's not IIS hosted, and has dynamic configuration (so it's not in the config file either). Does your config suggestion mean I would need to create seperate service hosts?

Comment: Yes, WCF requires each service definition to have its own host.